# Using multiple Treeview objects with the same (but cloned) itemssource

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, treeview

So, I have a `listview` with different `datatemplates` as seen here:

```
<ListView Panel.ZIndex="0" x:Name="FilterList" Margin="10,0" Grid.Row="2" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="White" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource 
    ReportFilterTemplateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding reportParameters, 
    Mode=TwoWay}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
```

One of my sample `datatemplates` can be seen below.  Everything shows up great.  My problem, is that for this (and other) `datatemplates`, I can have multiple instances of the same one.  In this particular instance, the `treeview` `itemssource` is bound to `DataContext.OfficeListText` to populate all the elements.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="office">
        <Grid MinHeight="35" MaxHeight="250">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding rpName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.OfficeListText, RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" ExpandDirection="Down">

                <TreeView Tag="{Binding rpParameter}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding 
                    Path=DataContext.OfficeList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                    FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}" 
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"/>
            </Expander>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The main problem with this is one, for instance, if I select an office in say the first `treeview`, the 2nd `treeview` shows the same.  Essentially I want them to have the same itemssource initially but have separate instances.  Since they are generated dynamically that is where I'm getting stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

I'm not sure what other code would be necessary, since I'm sure most of it will be irreverent based on what I'll need to do to make this work, but if you would like more I will gladly provide.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "if I select an office in say the first treeview, the 2nd treeview shows the same"?

Comment: Umm, the datatemplate is used on bound data... If you want different data sources, you should bind to separate instances... i believe you should be able to create an instance in resources of the control and bind to that, though i don't really get the whole picture from your question, so you might want to improve it...

Comment: @foosburger Say two of the "office" datatemplates are displayed, what happens on one affects the other. I'm assuming this is because the treeview itself is bound to the same `DataContext.OfficeList` instance.

Comment: @StefanDenchev you're exactly right, I need to bind to separate instances, I'm just not sure how to specify that each time the `datatemplate` is used that it will initialize a new instance of `DataContext.OfficeList`

Answer (score 0):

Currently your TreeView binds to a single instance of OfficeList that belongs to your UserControl's DataContext.  This means that every TreeView points to the same list.  If I understand your question correctly, what you really want is to have a different instance of OfficeList for each TreeView.

I don't recommend instantiating a new OfficeList each time the DataTemplate is applied to a reportParameter.  You could do that with a ValueConverter, but it would be pretty hacky.

The cleaner solution would be to have a class that contains the data for your reportParameter, plus an instance of OfficeList, and then bind to instances of that class instead of binding to the UserControl.  Depending on how the reportParameters are structured (I am going to assume that reportParameters is a list of objects of type ReportParameter), there are two ways you might want to do this:

1) If ReportParameter is a ViewModel, you can simply add an OfficeList property to the ReportParameter class, and initialize it when you instantiate each ReportParameter.

Then your TreeView would look like this:

```
<TreeView Tag="{Binding rpParameter}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OfficeList, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"/>
```

2) If ReportParameter is not a ViewModel (and thus it would not be appropriate to add an OfficeList parameter), then create a new class called something like ReportParameterViewModel that contains 2 properties: ReportParameter and OfficeList.  Instead of binding your ListView to a list of ReportParameter, bind to a list of ReportParameterViewModel.

Then your ListView will look something like this:

```
<ListView Panel.ZIndex="0" x:Name="FilterList" Margin="10,0" Grid.Row="2" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="White" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource 
    ReportFilterTemplateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding reportParameterViewModels, 
    Mode=TwoWay}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
```

Your TextBlock will look like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ReportParameter.rpName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
```

Your TreeView will look like this:

```
<TreeView Tag="{Binding rpParameter}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OfficeList, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"/>
```